# VoiceOver support is patchy

Tags: bug, ios-app, accessibility, voiceover

This is a list of mostly VoiceOver bugs or weirdnesses that I’ve found. I’ve put them all together because they’re all related, but I can break them out into separate questions if needed. Throughout the list below, assume VO is enabled.

Version 0.1.50, iPhone 5s, iOS 7.1

- A few of the icon-style buttons seem to have labels corresponding to their resource/icon name, rather than an accurate label. Examples:

  - Inbox icon in the top-right hand corner: “ico-inbox”
  - Filter arrows beside search fields: “ico-arrow”
  - Upvote/downvote arrows: “ico-upvote” “ico-downvote”
  - The swipe handles (three vertical lines/three dots) to discard comments/move from question to answers:
    “ico-grib”
    “ico-dots”
- The search bar and associated filter arrows behave oddly. Working from the title down, the filter arrows occur before the search bar. Further, the arrows are inaccessible if the user is editing in the search bar.

  Example steps:

  1. Open the list of Sites (“More Sites” in the sidebar).
  2. You start on the “Cancel” button. Swipe (right) once to get “Sites; heading”.
  3. Swipe twice more, and you get “ico-arrow” (the filter arrows), and then “Find the Stack Exchange site; is editing”. I think the search field should occur before the filter in the order of items.
  4. Double-tap on the search bar. “Text field; is editing; Find the Stack Exchange site”. Swiping right now takes you to the Cancel button, and then into the list of sites – although the filter button still works, it is inaccessible through VO.
- I can’t find the “Request failed. Tap to retry.” error that appears at the top of a question list in the list of items. Swiping through the VO items, you go straight from the inbox to the arrows, and skip over it.

  This means that if the question list isn’t populated (because of this error), there’s no feedback to the user. There’s no way to get to that error without tapping on it directly.

  However, if they select that area, then VO reads it aloud and double-tapping (the analog of tapping when VO is enabled) causes the list to refresh.
- Some parts of the app could be improved, so that there’s context for the numbers it reads out. Some examples:

  - **Questions in the question list.** These are read as “[title] [tags] [time] [score] [answers]”, but there’s no context to that information. For example:

    > Can I boil eggs in the same pot I’m boiling something else? Food safety. Eggs. Boiling. One hour. 19. 11.

    I’d suggest something more like:

    > Can I boil eggs in the same pot I’m boiling something else? **Tags.** Food safety. Eggs. Boiling. **Last updated.** One hour **ago**. **Score** 19. **Answers** 11. **Has an Accepted Answer.**

    Note also that when read aloud, there’s no way to distinguish between questions that have an accepted answer, and those which don’t.
  - **Badges.** On user profiles, the badge icons are labelled “black circle” and read out with no context. For example:

    > 18.4k. Black circle 3. Black circle 17. Black circle 42.

    This should be something more like

    > 18.4k reputation. 3 gold badges. 17 silver badges. 42 bronze badges.
  - **Network profile.** Items are read out in the wrong order.

    Here’s an example interaction:

    > Network Profile. Heading. (swipe)
    >
    > Italy. Username. (swipe)
    >
    > User’s URL. (swipe)
    >
    > 250k. Black circle 20. […] TeX - LaTeX (swipe)
    >
    > Top question 1 (swipe) Top question 2 (swipe) Top question 3 (swipe)
    >
    > 18k. Black circle 2. […] Black circle 40. Mathematics.

    I think the username should precede their location, and the site title should precede their list of badges.
  - **Feed.** I have no idea what’s going on here; I’m completely lost in VO.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response! I'll be adding VoiceOver support little by little.

Comment: @ArieLitovsky: Great, I’m glad to hear it’s being considered. As I find new bugs/old ones get closed, should I create new questions, or update this one? I notice a couple of things have already been fixed in 0.1.54 :)