# The voice over text for the picture control is listed as code button

Tags: bug, ios-app, accessibility, voiceover

First off, the voice over support of the iOS alpha app (v1.0.0.67) is incredibly good.

I'd change and fix several voice over tags on the post screen:

- The *ico styles* ?[sic?] button might be better labeled/spoken as **show text formatting buttons**? (or formatting keyboard)
- The *ico slide left* button might be better labeled/spoken as **hide formatting buttons**?
- The *picture button* is incorrectly spoken as *code button*
- swiping right from the picture button scrolls the list left and selects the ordered list button, swiping right again does not scroll the list and instead selects the *ico slide right* button. I would have the swipe continue to scroll and select, but at least make it consistent.
- selecting the *ico slide right* button skips several items. That would be very hard for someone using voiceover to discover if they can't actually see the screen to know what order the buttons are arranged. Try to keep the items in order left to right under voice over just as it appears visually.
- The left brace and right brace buttons are both labeled incorrectly as *horizontal line button*
- When voiceover describes a new user, it says *1 black circle 1* when the user has a single bronze badge and one rep total. Similarly, it categorizes gold and silver badge count as *black circle*.

Again, the accessibility of the app is quite awesome and I'd focus on fixing the labels and ordering of the editing buttons first and the others only if easy.

Comment: Some of these are already reported, but the thread there discusses version 0.0.50 so I figured a more specific, targeted list of problems was appropriate. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229930/voiceover-support-is-patchy None of my criticism needs a major overhaul, just some attention to detail in naming code items or adding explicit voiceover hints if needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bit long for a comment, so moving to an answer:

- ico-styles: [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
- ico-slide-left: [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) but the function of that button changes conditionally and we need text for the other case.
- Picture button: [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed). Oops, I copied the code button when I added it in.
- Swiping to page two: Generally, horizontal swipes advance to the next on-screen element in a zig-zag fashion, and scrolling is done with the *non-obvious* three finger swipe.  While it is probably possible, I'm not sure if it's a good idea.
- ico-slide-right: There's probably something better we can do here, akin to what UITableView does, where we announce the scroll and move the cursor. [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned)
- left/right bracket: [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
- user description: [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned), that's part of a bigger problem of how we render badges.

Back to the left and right buttons (slide left, slide right), I'm not sure what the best text to use for their titles (or hints) would be. Maybe something like "Next page Button, Double tap for more formatting options"

Comment: Excellent - the planned make sense if you are still working on how to present the controls / user data. Also, when I said "swipe" I means the voiceover swipe to move the "cursor" as opposed to the normal swipe multitouch gesture to interact with the icons themselves.